# Deleting Messages with time

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

So I want it to delete some specific messages if the date/Minutes is 55 and the month is this month! Although I got some Discord API errors as specified below!  I was trying to make a delay and to make sure that the msg even exists but no luck it gave me the same error!

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const editJsonFile = require("edit-json-file");
var fs = require('file-system');
var path = require('path');

const prefix = "v_";

let count;

exports.run = async (client, message, args, ops) => {
      const channel = client.channels.cache.get("813794049445462036");
      const channel2 = client.channels.cache.get("813801699469819984");
      const channelog = client.channels.cache.get("814561365510586400");
      const monthlog = client.channels.cache.get("814758448700719155");

      let number = editJsonFile(`premium/premium.json`);
      let endDate = editJsonFile(`premium/endate.json`);
      let count = editJsonFile(`premium/count.json`);
      let month = editJsonFile(`premium/month.json`);
      month.save();
      number.save();
      endDate.save();
      count.save();


      count.set(`p`, 0);
      count.set(`p1`, 0);
      count.save();

      let p = count.get(`p`);
      let p1 = count.get(`p1`);

      //Reset

      setTimeout(async function() {
        channel2.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {

        messages.forEach(async message => {
          p = count.get(`p`);
          p1 = count.get(`p1`);

          var today = new Date();
          var date = today.getMinutes()
          var montht = new Date();
          var monthcheck = montht.getMonth();
          if (date == 55) {
            setTimeout(async function() {
              monthlog.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {

              messages.forEach(message3 => {
                p = count.get(`p`);
                p1 = count.get(`p1`);
                console.log(monthcheck);
                if (message3.content == 2) {
                  let number = editJsonFile(`premium/premium.json`);
                  number.save();
                  const userid2 = number.get(`${p1}`);
                  setTimeout(async function() {
                    if (message != undefined){
                      await message.delete({ timeout: 250 });
                    }
                  }, 0)
                  setTimeout(async function() {
                    if (message3 != undefined){
                      await message3.delete({ timeout: 500 });
                    }
                  }, 1000)

                  setTimeout(async function() {
                    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {

                    messages.forEach(message2 => {
                        p = count.get(`p`);
                        p1 = count.get(`p1`);

                        console.log(userid2);
                        console.log(`${message2.content}`);
                        console.log(`${p1}`)
                        if(userid2 == message2.content) {
                          setTimeout(async function() {
                            await message2.delete({ timeout: 100 });
                          }, 0)
                          number = editJsonFile(`premium/premium.json`);
                          number.unset(`${p1}`)
                          number.save();
                        }
                    endDate.unset(`${p1}`);
                    endDate.save();
                    month.unset(`${p1}`);
                    month.save();


                    setTimeout(async function() {
                      channelog.send(` <@${userid2}>'s premium has expired from partnering!'`)
                    }, 500)
                    message.delete();
                  })
                })
              }, 5000)
            }
            else {
              p = count.get(`p`);
              p1 = count.get(`p1`);
              pf = count.get(`pf`);
              pf1 = count.get(`pf1`);
              if (p == p1) {
                endDate.set(`${p1}`, message.content)
                endDate.save();
                month.set(`${p1}`, message3.content)
                month.save();
              }
              else {
                endDate.set(`${p1}`, message.content)
                endDate.save();
                month.set(`${p1}`, message3.content)
                month.save();
                count.set(`p1`, p1+1);
                count.save();
              }
            }
          })
        })
      }, 3000);
    }
  })
})

    }, 5000)
      setTimeout(function() {
        channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {

        messages.forEach(message => {

              p = count.get(`p`);
              p1 = count.get(`p1`);


              number = editJsonFile(`premium/premium.json`);
              number.set(`${p}`, message.content)
              number.save();
              count = editJsonFile(`premium/count.json`);
              count.set(`p`, p+1);
              count.save();
        })
      })
    }, 1000)




      count = editJsonFile(`premium/count.json`);
      count.set(`p`, 0);
      count.set(`p1`, 0);
      count.save();
      number.save();

}
```

This is the error I got for both of the times I tested with my code:

```
C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154
      throw new DiscordAPIError(request.path, data, request.method, res.status);
            ^

DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async MessageManager.delete (C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\MessageManager.js:126:5)
    at async Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\cedri\Desktop\vibe-main\events\premium.js:60:23) {
  method: 'delete',
  path: '/channels/813801699469819984/messages/814796597518139413',
  code: 10008,
  httpStatus: 404
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Unknown Message` occurs most commonly when you are trying to delete a message that does not exist.

This is happening because you are using an unreliable syntax for finding the channels. `#get` was changed in V12, I would use `#find`.

To combat this, you should use

```js
await message.guild.channels.fetch(); //fetches all channels
const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.id === "<id here>");
```

To make sure you search through all channels, use an `await message.guild.channels.fetch()`

[Here](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#commonly-used-methods-that-changed) is the changelog for V12

Comment: I am trying to make this work but it keeps saying guild is undefined. What would I put to make sure the guild is defined for a specific server?

Comment: Guild should always be defined, if you have created your arguments correctly. In your handler where did you define your message arguments?

Comment: what do you mean by message arguments?

Comment: If you have created your handler correctly, `guild`, which is part of the `message` object, will be defined. The reason it would say `guild` is undefined is because you have not set up `message` correctly in your handler

Comment: I have tried doing the following but even there it still says "Guild not defined":
```const guild = client.guilds.cache.get("809466736491233290");```

Comment: Okay, this is because you are using keywords for variables, which is never recommended. Please change your `guild` variable to something else - like `guildChosen`

Comment: I tried changing it and it still gives me the same error!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229263/discussion-between-joe-moore-and-chilled-bluefire).